# Error lvalue required as unary '&' operand, when passing function to a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers, lvalue

I am just getting familiar with how to pass function as a parameter to another function, and with pointers/C overall as well.

I have the following function that takes another function:

```
void func(void (*vect) (float *, float), float *x1, float size)
{
    vect(&x1, size);
    // other instructions
}
```

This is how `foo` is defined (`foo` is the `vect` that I pass to the function):

```
void foo(float *x1, float size)
{
    //
}
```

And this is how I am using the function `func`

```
func(&foo(&x1, size), &x1, size);
```

For some reason I am getting the following error:

`error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand`

Would anyone share his insight on why is that happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this:

```
&foo(&x1, size)
```

You are *calling* the function and attempting to take the address of its return value.  Since the return type of `foo` is `void`, you can't take its address, hence the error.

When using a pointer to a function, use *just* the name of the function, not the function call operator `()`:

```
func(foo, &x1, size);
```

Also, this is incorrect:

```
vect(&x1, size);
```

Since `&x1` has type `float **` but `vect` expects its first argument to be of type `float *`.  You instead want:

```
vect(x1, size);
```

Comment: This clarifies everything for me. Thanks. I will accept as soon as available.